# Unicode superscript encoding rule

Tags: unicode, superscript

The following UTF-8 sequence `\x6D\xE1\xB5\x90` creates a 'm' with a superscript 'm': 'mᵐ'.

What is the Unicode encoding rule for this? How to create a 'x<sup>x</sup>' or any other arbitrary superscript?

Comment: There is no superscript encoding here. You have used the character ["MODIFIER LETTER SMALL M"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d50/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "rule". [U+1D50](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d50/index.htm) is a literal superscript `m` glyph.

There are similar glyphs for selected parts the basic Latin alphabet and the numbers; https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/superscripts_and_subscripts/list.htm

There is no general mechanism to produce a superscripted version of any arbitrary glyph.

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts and https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=superscript